# 502 bad gateway error with pywhatkit library

Tags: python, nginx, flask, google-app-engine

I am trying to send messages to WhatsApp using pywhatkit.
Flask Framework is used. Locally, it is running perfectly but when I deployed the code on google cloud it is giving me a 502 bad gateway error. I have enabled google sheet API and cloud build API. I am unable to identify my mistake.

```
from flask import Flask,request,render_template
import pywhatkit
import pickle
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import itertools  
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return render_template("test.html")

@app.route('/calling',methods=['POST','GET'])
def contact():
    if request.method == 'POST':

        if request.form['submit_button'] == 'send message to numbers from 1 to 10,000':

            SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = '**********.json'

            SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
            creds = None
            creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
            # The ID and range of a sample spreadsheet.
            SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID = '*************'
            service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
            sheet = service.spreadsheets()


            result1 = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,range="whatsaap!A2:A100").execute()
            hour= result1.get('values')
            hour = list(itertools.chain(*hour))
         

            result2 = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,range="whatsaap!B2:B100").execute()
            minute= result2.get('values')
            minute = list(itertools.chain(*minute))
          

            result3 = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,range="whatsaap!C2:C100").execute()
            number= result3.get('values')
            number = list(itertools.chain(*number))
     


            for i,j, k in zip(number,hour, minute):

                j= int(j)
                k= int(k)
                print(f'Output:\n{i}\n{j}\n{k}')
                pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg(i, 'hello dear, Auto whatsaap message testing', j ,k)
                time.sleep(35)

            return 'Done with messanging to numbers from 1 to 10,000' 

                
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

getting this error :
[image: error]

logs :
[image: logs]

[image: logs]

Locally running :
[image: locally running]

Comment: error shows `127.0.0.1` so server can't be acccessed from internet. It may need `app.run(host="0.0.0.0")` OR if this runs with gunicorn on nginx then it may need special port configured in nginx - ie. `app.run(port=8081)`

Comment: You could start with simpler version - only `hello_world` and `Flask` module - to see if it will work. later you can use `print()` to see which line of code is execute and what you have in variables. Maybe it needs different values.

Comment: first image shows error in `nginx` so problem can be communication between `nginx`, `gunicorn` and `flask` - and you should read full `Traceback` in log.

Comment: @SamiyaJabbar, any progress? Have you managed to deploy  a test app on App Engine?

Comment: @furas I tried app.run(host="0.0.0.0") and app.run(port=8081) but still same error

Comment: you should check what exactly you have in log - you show image with only partial text in log and there is `Traceback ... gunicorn ...` so your code is run by `gunicorn` and it may have problem to run it.  You have to read full text in log to see what really is the problem. Gunicorn doesn't use `app.run()` from your code but it should `import app` and run own `app.run()`

Comment: OR you should start with the simplest code - only `Flask` with `hello world` without other modules. And if this will work then add modules one by one and test new code. It may have problem to run some of modul. Maybe some module has to be installed on server.